# Excel Vba click radio button with application.caller

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which run function (clear each named range depend ot application.caller.name) if radio button was clicked

```
Sub Clear_Click()


Dim s, f, arr
s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
arr = Array("NamedArray1", "NamedArray2", "NamedArray3", "NamedArray4")
Select Case s
    Case "Clear7"
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info").Range(arr(i)).value = ""
        Next i
    Case Else
        f = arr(Right(s, 1) - 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info").Range(f).value = ""
End Select

End Sub
```

It works ok.

Now i need to click Clear7 radio button from other function
So if i do

```
Sub test()
Application.Run ActiveSheet.Shapes("Clear7").OnAction
End Sub
```

I got error on `s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name` as there are no Application.Caller i think.

So how to click radio button from other function?

Comment: I honestly don't get why you use `ActiveSheet` when you are planning to access functions/subs with object references.

Comment: Is it so hard for you to set the worksheet as a reference object and also send the radio button object reference as a paramter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Application.Caller but you want to run the code without someone needing to click the button then here's how you can do it.

**NOTE:** since Clear_Click has an argument, it won't show up in the "assign macro" list when attaching it to a button, but you can type its name directly in the box and that will work fine.

```
Sub Clear_Click(Optional callerName As String = "")

    Dim s, f, arr, cn As String, i
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    cn = IIf(Len(callerName) > 0, callerName, Application.Caller)
    'Debug.Print cn

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info")
    arr = Array("NamedArray1", "NamedArray2", "NamedArray3", "NamedArray4")

    Select Case cn
        Case "Clear7"
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                sht.Range(arr(i)).Value = ""
            Next i
        Case Else
            f = arr(Right(s, 1) - 1)
            sht.Range(f).Value = ""
    End Select

End Sub


Sub test()
    ClickIt "Clear7"
End Sub

'run a macro attached to a shape and pass its name as a parameter
Sub ClickIt(sName As String)
    Application.Run ActiveSheet.Shapes(sName).OnAction, sName
End Sub
```